# How to interface an isolated microcontroller to an integrated h-bridge?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, h-bridge, isolation

I have an ESP32S3 microcontroller powered by an [isolated DC-DC converter](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/URA2405YMD-20WR3.html)
and I would like to use this [integrated h-bridge](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vnh7040ay.pdf) to control a DC motor. The power supply can be either 12 or 24V.

My gut feeling tells me this will not work as the isolated return of the microcontroller is different from the integrated bridge. Am I missing something here? Why a sophisticated and integrated bridge chip would not have an isolated return too? Any ideas or workarounds suggestions?

Comment: Go to digikey.com and search for digital isolators.

Comment: Awesome. Go it!

Comment: Is the isolation mandatory? If not you could tie off the grounds and the bridge chip would work just fine.